# Fastest Way to Generate Range of Numbers

Tags: firebird, firebird-3.0

What is the fastest way to generate numbers between two values.

For example:
*1st Value: 6,000,000

2nd Value: 7,500,000*
I have to create 1,500,000 rows like below

```
 6,000,001
 6,000,002
 .
 .
 7,500,000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
create or alter procedure GET_INTEGER_RANGE (
INICIO integer,
FIN integer)
returns (
    ACTUAL integer)
AS
begin
  actual = inicio;
  while (actual<=fin) do
  begin
       suspend;
       actual = actual +1;
  end
end

SELECT * FROM GET_INTEGER_RANGE(6000000,7500000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the fastest, but it's the only way I can think of:

```
with recursive numbers (nr) as (
   select 6000000 
   from rdb$database
   union all
   select nr + 1
   from numbers
   where nr < 7500000
)
select * 
from numbers;
```

---

**Update:** as franbenz pointed out in the comment, Firebird is limited to a recursion depth of 1024 which apparently cannot be changed. So while the basic syntax is correct the above will not work when trying to generate more then 1024 rows.

Comment: According to the Firebird 2.1 language reference, the maximum recursion depth is 1024. This is affecting the execution for ranges above 1024.

Comment: @franbenz: ah, thanks. I wasn't aware of that limitation. Then of course this won't help.